# Consequences of overstaying Schengen visa for 6 months

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, overstaying

So, as the title read I happened to overstayed my Schengen visa for 6 months does anyone know what the consequences could be. If I wanted to return back to Saudi Arabia.

Comment: Related: [What is the penalty for exceeding the 90 day limit in Rome on an US passport](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/21596/32134) and [Can an over-stayed stamp from one country affect my abillity to travel to other countries?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/47128/32134). In short, you might be fined, banned for future Schengen visas and have a hard time getting visas in other countries. Also related [Best way to leave EU with expired visa](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/43374/32134)

Answer (score 4):

Immediate consequences are that your exit will be recorded in the Schengen-wide SIS database.

This means that the next time you apply for a Schengen visa (and possibly, for other visas) your application will have to go additional scrutiny and has a high chance of being denied.

As far as Saudi Arabia is concerned - as long as you have a valid visa (or don't need one), you will have no problems entering the country.

Unfortunately each member state is free to enforce their own rules when it comes to sanctions for overstaying.  There are stories all over the Internet of heavy fines, jail time, questions ... but in the end no one was denied exit.